# adding 2 conditions in data validation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If cell A109 = "test1" or "test2" and cell B109 is empty, I dont want to be able to fill cell B111.

My formula isn't working. What is wrong?

here is the formula :=AND( OR(A109=""Test1"", A109=""Test2""), NOT(ISBLANK(B109)) )"

EDIT :

VBA CODE:

```
Sub Macro2()

If Range("A109").Value = "Processus de non certifié" Or Range("A109").Value = "Processus d'installation non connu" Then


    Range("B111").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=AND( OR(A109=""Processus de non certifié"", A109=""Processus d'installation non connu""), NOT(ISBLANK(B109)) )"
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = "ATTENTION!"
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = _
        "Vous ne pouvez faire la remise en service tant que vous n'avez pas approuvé le ""...."" ou ""...."" à la cellule B109."
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Sheets("Grille").Select
Else
    Exit Sub

    
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to add it in the "Data validation" tool. I dont want to use VBA. Isn't it possible? @BigBen

Comment: I removed it. I used the formula in VBA, then decided to keep it simple. I just tried to help you guys with giving you an idea of the error by adding what vba compiler said.

Comment: What is the complete line used in VBA?

Comment: @P.b I edited the question to add the vba code